# Elasticsearch combine two different queries types in one request

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, bigdata

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to combine two query types, in my case I need a queryString and filtered query, each has to operate on a different field.
the query filtered get all record who's in `$postids` 
`$postids:multiple` value of post_id 
and the query string is to search a words in text 
Currently I need two requests to archive this:
Query filtered:

```
GET /myindex1/tweecoms/_search
{
"query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "post_id" : ['.$postids.']
                }
            }
        }
}

query String:

GET /myindex1/tweecoms/_search{
 "query": {
                   "query_string": {
                        "query": "*' . $sujet . '*",
                        "lenient": true
                    }
                    }
}
```

and I tried to combine it

```
GET /myindex1/tweecoms/_search

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
           "query_string": {
                        "query": "hhhh",
                        "lenient": true
                    }
        },
        {
          "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "post_id" : [0,157]
                }
            }
        }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`
```

but what i try run just the query string

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write query inside `filtered` clause. [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_combining_queries_with_filters.html) will help you understand.
Try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "post_id": [0,157]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with your query is you are using should clause which will select either documents with given query string or those with given post_ids. You can replace `should` with `must` and will get expected results.

You could also use [minimum_should_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) parameter inside your query

I hope this helps

Comment: what I want to do is have 2 results, not filter the query the query string me I want to filter the data the query string I want to have the results of the query string and the results of the filter, that is what I want is that in the second query I want him to show me the record that the post_id example post_id in [0,1,2] and thank you for your answer